# How to avoid confirmation message from browser when form is submitted at onclick event of a span?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts-1

This is the initial state of the JSP page, with one set of data looks like this

[image]

If the client clicks on the **+** icon or **Click here** label the form should be submitted and the list will be increased which will look like

[image]

The form submission is proper when **+** icon is clicked, but when **Click here** label is clicked the browser is asking a confirmation message

[image]

The JSP code portion is :-

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick= "addEvaluators('addEvaluators')">
                <font color="#228B22">Click here</font>&nbsp;
                <img src="images/admission/images/12673199831854453770medical cross button.svg.med.png" width="20px" height="20px" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            </span>
            to increase evaluators
        </td>                                               
    </tr>
    <logic:equal name="paperEvaluationUpdateEntryForm" property="showRemoveButton" value="true">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="removeEvaluators('removeEvaluators')">
                    <font color="#B22222">Click here</font>&nbsp;
                    <img src="images/admission/images/15107-illustration-of-a-red-close-button-pv.png" width="22px"; height="22px"; style="vertical-align:middle;">
                </span>
                to decrease evaluators
            </td>
        </tr>
    </logic:equal>
</table>
```

The **Javascript** code I wrote is :-

```
function addEvaluators(method) {
    document.getElementById("method").value=method;
    document.paperEvaluationUpdateEntryForm.submit();
}
```

The reason why I kept both the image and label inside a **span** tag is because I want the **form** to be submitted at the **onclick** event of both and **font** tag is not having an **onclick** event.

My question is why that confirmation message is coming when the label is clicked, which is not happening when the image is clicked, and how to avoid it?

Comment: Do not use a font tag.... It has been obsolete for ages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add  below code in onSubmit method

`window.onbeforeunload=null;`

This will skip alert function.

Comment: Thanks **@Rupesh Dhadiwal**, it worked. But can you please tell me why that message comes only when the label is clicked?

Comment: because you some value assigned to window.onbeforeunload